# convert iso 4217 numeric currency code to currency name

Tags: java, iso, applepay

I have a an ISO 4217 numeric currency code: `840`

I want to get the currency name: `USD`

I am trying to do this:

```
 Currency curr1 = Currency.getInstance("840");
```

But I keep getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

how to fix? any ideas?

Comment: You have to provide a `Locale`.

Comment: I can also provide a string: getInstance(String currencyCode)
Returns the Currency instance for the given currency code.

Comment: Can I get the locale from the numeric code?

Comment: If you just want to map code to currency unit, why not using a map? http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`java.util.Currency.getInstance` supports only ISO 4217 currency **codes**, not currency numbers. However, you can retrieve all currencies using the `getAvailableCurrencies` method, and then search for the one with code 840 by comparing the result of the `getNumericCode` method.

Like this:

```
public static Currency getCurrencyInstance(int numericCode) {
    Set<Currency> currencies = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();
    for (Currency currency : currencies) {
        if (currency.getNumericCode() == numericCode) {
            return currency;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Currency with numeric code "  + numericCode + " not found");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

With Java 8:

```java
Optional<Currency> currency = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().stream().filter(c -> c.getNumericCode() == 840).findAny();
```

Answer (score 5):

A better way to do it:

```
public class CurrencyHelper {

    private static Map<Integer, Currency> currencies = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        Set<Currency> set = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();
        for (Currency currency : set) {
             currencies.put(currency.getNumericCode(), currency);
        }
    }

    public static Currency getInstance(Integer code) {
        return currencies.get(code);
    }
}
```

With a little work the cache can be made more efficient. Please take a look at the source code the Currency class for more information.

Comment: I noticed that this code block did not perform efficiently during my tests. I believe it should not be used in this manner."

Answer (score 1):

I have reviewed other comments as well, but the most efficient working version is as follows:

```java
public final class CurrencyFinder {

    private CurrencyFinder() {
    }

    private static final Set<Currency> AVAILABLE_CURRENCIES = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();

    public static Optional<Currency> find(String currencyCode) {
        return AVAILABLE_CURRENCIES.stream()
                .filter(currency -> Objects.equals(currency.getCurrencyCode(), currencyCode))
                .findFirst();
    }

    public static Optional<Currency> find(Integer numericCode) {
        return AVAILABLE_CURRENCIES.stream()
                .filter(currency -> currency.getNumericCode() == numericCode)
                .findFirst();
    }

}
```

> While making these transformations, I noticed that some `numericCode` values are the same, which I consider to be an important point to be aware of. Especially if a project is to be undertaken, I recommend working with the `currencyCode` value instead of the `numericCode` value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide code like "USD" and then it will return Currency object. If you are using JDK 7 then you can use following code. JDk 7 has a  method  getAvailableCurrencies()

```
public static Currency getCurrencyByCode(int code) {
    for(Currency currency : Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()) {
        if(currency.getNumericCode() == code) {
            return currency;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unkown currency code: " + code);
}
```